# I want to update custom field of Project Server 2010 using CSOM code, Is it possible to execute?

Tags: sharepoint-server, project-server

I want to update custom field of Project Server 2010 using CSOM code, is it possible to execute? i am not able to get Microsoft.ProjectServer.Client.dll on internet, actually i dont have access for Project server 2010, how i can download?

Answer (score 1):

If you have already installed [Project Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/project/project-server-2013-and-2016) you can do this.

As mentioned [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/previous-versions/office/project-class/jj236068(v=office.15)) , You can reference to this library again by just going into this path and select the dll file.

2010:

> %ProgramFiles%\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server
>   Extensions\14\ISAPI\Microsoft.ProjectServer.Client.dll

2013:

> %ProgramFiles%\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server
>   Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.ProjectServer.Client.dll

Comment: Thanks for update, But i dont have have access to for Project Server, can you please help me to download 2010 version because i already tried to install PS2010 sdk but i am not able to found dlls